# wurfl2 integration in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, wurfl

everytime i try to install the wurfl2 extension in TYPO3 i get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php/lib/php:/usr/local/php/lib/php/PEAR') in /html/typo3conf/temp_CACHED_ps9b8e_ext_localconf.php on line 501
```

is anyone familiar with this error and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error message with TYPO3 4.4.4. I had to remove the extension folder and to delete all ./typo3conf/temp* files to get Typo3 running again afterwards.
(You might not see the error message if you don't have something like $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['displayErrors'] = '1' in your localconf.php. You can set this with the installtool.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by the other answer first you have to get your system running again: set $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['displayErrors'] = '1' in your localconf.php in order to see all error messages. Afterwards remove the extension folder.

I think the error is caused by a missing config file. The extension constant wurflConfig has to be set with the absolute path to the file /YOUR/PATH/TO/WEB_DIR/typo3conf/ext/wurfl2/res1/li/wurfl_config.php and might have to adjust the settings there.